# What would 0x88 literal cast to in c++?

Tags: c++, casting, literals

I thought a literal like `0x88` would cast to `signed int`. but the output of the following program is different from my initial assumption. Could somebody please shed some light on this and explain what's happening?

```
printf("%hd, %hu\n", 0x88); // output: 136 (10001000), 65416 (11111111 10001000)
```

If my assumption was correct, `0x88` first would be cast to `signed int` and become:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 10001000
```

When printing with `%hd`, it would be cast to `signed short` which yields:

```
00000000 10001000
```

and printing it with `%hd` would cast it to `unsigned short` which again yields this:

```
00000000 10001000
```

I expected the output of both `printf`s to be 136.

***update***: One of the parameters of `printf` was missing mistakenly. It should've been as you guys pointed out:

```
printf("%hd, %hu\n", 0x88, 0x88);
```

Comment: Put another `0x88` into the argument list of `printf()`. I think you're simply seeing undefined behavior.

Comment: I predict that this will soon turn out to be a brown-paperbag question. :-)

Comment: OK - I'll bite - what's a "brown-paperbag question" ?

Comment: @LinusKleen That won't help either. He would also have to cast both parameters to `short int` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: proper compilers should emit a warning for that.. what do you use?

Comment: @LinusKleen oops! that was my fault!

Comment: @yi_H compiler version: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ all literals have a type, they don't "cast to". The type of integer literals without any further suffix is the smallest integer big enough to represent the value, but no smaller than int.

So the type of `0x88` is `int`.

As such, your printf must be:

```
printf("%d",0x88);
```

Note that:

- Your `printf("%hd, %hu\n", 0x88);` is invoking UB as it has more format specifiers than parameters.
- Using different format specifiers than parameters will not do any casts, it will in the worst case also invoke UB. So when you want to use format specifier `%hd` for `short int` the type of the argument must be the same too.

Comment: Yes. That said, the vast majority of compilers won't mind if the argument to a %hd is not a short int; the implementation is the same as for an int. (i.e. most 32-bit systems will push 4 bytes even for a short int.)

Comment: @MrLister: Strictly, this is still invoking UB. And today the number of implementations and architectures people use seem to be increasing; it gets more and more common for people to program in C or C++ for 64bit desktops, tablets, smartphones, TVs, media devices, GPUs etc. all with more or less "uncommon" architectures. When it is as easy as in this case, we should do it right at the start. Already on big endian architectures, this might fail, you don't have to be exotic.

Comment: I'm not sure it's UB. You can't actually pass a `short` to vararg functions such as `printf`, they're automatically promoted to `int`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875670/is-there-any-way-to-retrieve-a-float-from-a-varargs-functions-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Beware of variadic functions. `printf` expects as many arguments (plus the format itself) as there are specifiers, and here you have 2 specifiers but only one argument to format.

If you use a [correct line](http://ideone.com/2M6tQ):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  std::printf("%hd, %hu\n", 0x88, 0x88);
}
```

You will see:

```
136, 136
```

Comment: Just curious, does you platform by any chance have `short int` the same size as `int`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: no (see http://ideone.com/VHevy ), so I expect only the two first bytes of `int` to be printed. And it's probably a little endian machine.

Comment: How the heck does that work correctly with a variadric function? Does it align all parameters to 4 bytes? (edit: actually that makes a lot of sense, now that I think about it)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: yes, for variadic functions all arguments are generally aligned to the maximum alignment (4 or 8 bytes usually, that is the pointer size). It means there is "unused" padding between the arguments. Of course, this is an implementation detail, it's not supposed to be used. See http://ideone.com/asKUo

Comment: The machine is irrelevant.  When passing an argument to a `...`, integral promotion occurs, and in `printf` and company, the argument corresponding to an `%hd` will first be extracted as an `int`, then converted to a `short`; the conversion, here, is the equivalent of a `static_cast`, so if the value of the `int` is representable in the `short`, the results will be numerically correct.  Regardless of the endian-ness.

Comment: @JamesKanze: How does this work for `long` though, this would savagely "truncate" the value ?

Comment: @Matthieu M. : Formally UB, in practice it will depend on stack layout, integer sizes and endian-ness.

Comment: @MatthieuM. How does what work for long.  Each format specifier requires a specific type.  If you don't pass the correct type (after promotion and the other implicit conversions which apply), then you have undefined behavior.  In this case, he's passing an `int` (`0x88`) to a conversion specifier (`"%hd"`) which requires an `int`.  The behavior is well defined, and endian-ness doesn't enter into it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: ah sorry, I was speaking about transporting the arguments from the outside of `printf` to within, which I doubt depends on the "format".